# I am getting the error "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: docker

I am trying to run an image that I pulled from a system I inherited, and I am getting this cryptic error message.

```
docker run bc189eaeb16d /bin/bash
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

What exactly is going on? Do I need to mount some volume? I've googled this error message but nothing seems relevant

Comment: Why do you call the error "cryptic"? It clearly states that there is no `/bin/bash` binary inside the image. If you are sure that it _is_ - add more details (Dockerfile, etc.).

Comment: The only Dockerfile I have (I inherited this) says this: FROM jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres

# COPY /themes /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/
# COPY /deployments /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/
COPY ./standalone-ha.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/

Comment: The last command on a similar container I am trying to replicate is: /opt/jboss/docker-entrypoint.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config standalone-ha.xml

Comment: Are you sure `bc189eaeb16d` is based from `jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres`? The error used `jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres` to run a container totally different with what you post. Please share a correct dockerfile, if not have, also please tag your local image & push to dockerhub for folks to check. Or you may omit something in the post which maybe you think not important but in fact really related to the root cause.

Comment: Many images based on Alpine Linux don't have GNU Bash.  Most images have some sort of POSIX-compliant `/bin/sh` though.

Comment: @atline - I don't know. I pulled this image from a repository, and I am fairly new to Docker. I am trying to troubleshoot and debug it to figure out why I can't get the image working.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to override `jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres` image's default entrypoint. I tried the following command

```
docker run -it jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres /bin/bash
```

but I got a different error than yours, but this error makes things clearer. The error is:

```
WFLYSRV0073: Invalid option '/bin/bash'   
Usage: standalone.sh [args...]
where args include: A list of supported arguments
```

which means that the custom entrypoint that you think it will be executed is supplied as additional argument to jboss's `standalone.sh` script.

Try with this command to override default image's entrypoint:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/sh" jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres
```

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Comment: I think we're closer - but I am getting this message:  docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/sh" bc189eaeb16d
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.

Comment: What is `bc189eaeb16d`? Image hash or container hash? What is your host's OS? Windows? If yes ensure that all files copied to the container have LF endings.

Comment: Image hash. I saved an image so I would think it would save the context but it appears not to. I am running this on MacOS.

Comment: If you execute another command does it work? Try `docker run -it --entrypoint "pwd" bc189eaeb16d `.

Comment: It does not. docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"pwd\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown. - maybe a corrupted image?

Comment: Then something is wrong with the image. Did you try with `docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/sh" jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres`. Also it will be nice if you include your dockerfile in the OP. Maybe continue in chat..

Comment: When I try that, I get: Unable to find image 'jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres:latest' locally

Comment: I am trying to push the image up to docker hub, but I haven't done this before so it is taking me a second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196712/discussion-between-leopal-and-andrew-alexander).

Comment: According to the error, you are executing something that is not allowed on your image. Could you check what the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your Dockerfile contains ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your docker image doesn't include the bash shell.

- If you have access to the Dockerfile you can see from which parent image this one extends
- If you don't have access to the Dockerfile and want to get more information you can use the [inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_inspect/) command to get more information about this image. `docker inspect bc189eaeb16d`
- You can also try `docker run bc189eaeb16d /bin/sh` or `docker run bc189eaeb16d sh`  and see if that works.

**Update:** Based on your feedback it seems that your image extends from the image named [jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres/dockerfile).

If you follow the extension path of the docker files you will notice that it takes you all the way down to the [centos:7](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) image which has the bash shell.

[jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres/dockerfile) > [jboss/keycloak-postgres](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/server/Dockerfile) > [jboss/base-jdk:8](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/base-jdk/blob/jdk8/Dockerfile) > [jboss/base:latest](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/base/blob/master/Dockerfile) > [centos:7](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/9a389e11460bd809bb83c5fd4f095dbc8398d8cc/docker/Dockerfile)

My suggestion is to follow the instructions provided in the usage section of the [jboss/keycloak-ha-postgress](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres) site and once the containers are running try [attaching](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to them.

Comment: Same error with /bin/sh. Dockerfile is literally just copying something: COPY ./standalone-ha.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/